# WIndows XP file path in Windows Vista?

Tags: sql-server

I am looking for a SQL Server file I am supposed to delete, only the instructions I found for this are for Windows XP and my OS is Windows Vista.

And as ridiculous as this is, I cannot find this file path in Vista:

C:\Documents and Settings\YOUR_USERNAME\Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Data\SQLEXPRESS

can someone help me out?

EDIT:

ok guys, well what I am actually trying to do is resolve an Web developer 2008 express edition connection to sql server 2005 express issue that I am having.

So I found this page, and I am trying to accomplish set 2 but cannot find the file in my own computer anywhere!

http://www.aspdotnetfaq.com/Faq/fix-error-Failed-to-generate-a-user-instance-of-SQL-Server-due-to-a-failure-in-starting-the-process-for-the-user-instance.aspx

Comment: This question would be better suited at serverfault.com.

Comment: Actually, superuser would be better.  This is just a general xp=>vista question.  It's only incidental that he's looking for a sql server db file.

Comment: oops...sorry i will ask there then

Comment: Hello, welcome to SuperUser. Your question has been migrated here, where it is more adapted. To regain ownership over your question, you should create an account here, and associate it with your ServerFault account in user options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think in Vista this would be:

```
C:\Users\YOUR_USERNAME\AppData\Local\Microsoft.....
```

AppData is a hidden folder, in case you can't find it in Windows Explorer.

Comment: yeah i tried to search through everything that is under me, and I can find nothing that points to 'local settings' or any folder taht is similiar. so that is why i just asked cause i thought perhaps i was way off. thanks!

Comment: UH YEAH..."me" being my username. :D

Answer (score 1):

I thought it might have to do with 64 bit stuff... Googled; found this: 
http://kometbomb.net/2009/05/07/migrating-from-32-bit-xp-to-64-bit-windows-7/

> The Application Data and the Local
>   Settings\Application Data folders that
>   previously were right under the user
>   directory are now in
>   C:\Users\kometbomb\AppData\ and
>   C:\Users\kometbomb\AppData\Local\,
>   respectively. I just dropped the
>   Firefox and Thunderbird profile
>   folders in there and here I am again
>   with the same setup.

Comment: That's just Vista & 7 vs. XP. Not related to 32-bit vs. 64-bit.

Answer (score 1):

`%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Data\SQLEXPRESS`

Environment variables are the way to go, easier to remember and easier to navigate around with.  There are additional ones [here](http://vistaonwindows.com/environment_variables.html) if you are interested.